# Is there a way to loop through using the four basic operations in C?

Tags: c, loops, iteration

I am trying to find a way to use loops in order to calculate the result of every combination of 3 operators and 4 integers, and I was wondering if there is a way to have a loop run 4 times, each time using a different operator.

It's intended to work something like this, but I'm not sure how possible it is.

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   if (i == 0) {
      operator = '+';
   } else if (i == 1) {
      operator = '-';
   } else if (i == 2) {
      operator = '*';
   } else if (i == 3) {
      operator = '/';
   }

   printf("Result: %d\n", a operator b);
}
```

And the output would print results of 5, -1, 6, and 0...

But as I have read, operators cannot be put into variables, which is where I'm stuck.

If anyone could give me some insight as to how I could get around this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it’s important for you to separate the operation choice and its execution, you can use a function pointers:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
   return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
   return a - b;
}

int mul(int a, int b)
{
   return a * b;
}

int dv(int a, int b)
{
   return a / b;
}


int main()
{

   int (*op)(int, int);
   int a = 2;
   int b = 3;
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
         op = add;
      } else if (i == 1) {
         op = sub;
      } else if (i == 2) {
         op = mul;
      } else if (i == 3) {
         op = dv;
      }
      printf("Result: %d\n", op(a, b));
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Or you can simplify the if/else chain by using an array of pointers

```
typedef int (*OP)(int, int);
.............................
OP ops[] = {add, sub, mul, dv};
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   printf("Result: %d\n", ops[i](a, b));
}
```

Comment: Replace that if/else chain with an array of function pointers.

Comment: `result = ops[i](a,b);`

Comment: Also note: `div` is a standard function and thus the name is reserved with external linkage or if `stdlib.h` is included, so you should rename it. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! And if I nested 2 more loops in order to use 3 operators in total, would I need to make 12 functions to avoid rewriting the definition of op? Or can I add more statements such as " int (*op2)(int, int); " to account for the next operation?

Comment: @jake_wahle,  You do not need to rewrite functions. You can create as many pointers as you like.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka I appreciate all the help! This info was instrumental in helping me complete my school project in an efficient way. We haven't learned anything whatsoever about pointers so I'm not sure what they expected us to use

Answer (score 2):

You can use function pointers like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OP_NUM 4

typedef int(*op_f)(int, int);

typedef struct _ops {
        op_f fp;
        char * ops;
}ops;

int add (int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
}

int sub (int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
}

int mul (int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
}

int dv (int a, int b) {
        return a / b;
}

int main (void) {
        ops st_op[OP_NUM] = {   {add, "+"},
                                {sub, "-"},
                                {mul, "*"},
                                {dv, "/"}
                            };

        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < OP_NUM; i++) {
                printf ("%d %s %d : %d\n", a, st_op[i].ops, b, st_op[i].fp(a, b));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
2 + 3 : 5
2 - 3 : -1
2 * 3 : 6
2 / 3 : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

By far the simplest approach would be to include your operators in a character string and then loop over each character in the string passing each character through a `switch()` statement that evaluates your expression based on the operator, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int a = 2,
        b = 3;
    const char *ops = "+-*/";           /* constant string of operators */

    for (int i = 0; ops[i]; i++) {      /* loop over each operator (char) */
        int result = 0;

        switch (ops[i]) {               /* switch on each operator (char) */
            case '+': result = a + b;       /* addition */
                break;
            case '-': result = a - b;       /* subtraction */
                break;
            case '*': result = a * b;       /* multiplication */
                break;
            case '/': result = a / b;       /* division */
                break;
            default:
                fputs ("invalid operator.\n", stderr);  /* invalid operator */
                continue;                               /* go get next char */
        }
        /* output result */
        printf ("Result: %d %c %d = % d\n", a, ops[i], b, result);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/switch_operator
Result: 2 + 3 =  5
Result: 2 - 3 = -1
Result: 2 * 3 =  6
Result: 2 / 3 =  0
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.